# access specific Angular2 child component with same tags in Jasmine unit tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have 2 x child components in parent.component.html

```
<div class="form-control">
  <incr [formController]="formModel.controls['qty']"></incr>
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <incr [formController]="formModel.controls['price']"></incr>
</form>
```

in my jasmine unit test I am trying to test if right controller passed in each instance of the child-component

```
let mockCmp = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(mockIncr)).injector.get(mockIncr);
```

My question is how I can query specific child component. so I can have my assertions like this

```
expect(mockCmp.formController).toEqual(component.formModel.controls['price']);

expect(mockCmp2.formController).toEqual(component.formModel.controls['qty']);
```